# execute immediate statement in nested loop does not work PL/SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic, plsql

```
create or replace procedure NN(k number) as

cursor cursor1 IS 
select id,x,y from query_points;

cursor cursor2 IS
select x,y from data_points;

sid number;

x1 number;
y1 number;

x2 number;
y2 number;

dist number;
result number;

begin
open cursor1;

loop
    execute immediate 'delete from temp';
    fetch cursor1 into sid, x1, y1;

    exit when cursor1%notfound;


    for rec in (select x,y from data_points) loop
        x2 := rec.x;
        y2 := rec.y;

        dist:= sqrt(((x2-x1)**2)+((y2-y1)**2)); 

        execute immediate 'insert into temp values('||dist||')';    
    end loop;
    select distance into result from temp where rownum=k order by distance;
    execute immediate 'insert into nn_results values('||sid||','||k||','||result||')';
end loop;

close cursor1;
end;
```

The dynamic sql statements in this procedure do not execute when in a loop but execute individually.

Also, the procedure does not terminate. It causes google chrome to crash.

Anyone with experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is not necessary in this context. Try it as:

```
create or replace procedure NN(k number) as
  dist number;
  result number;
begin
  for aRow IN (select id,x,y from query_points)
  loop
    delete from temp;

    for rec in (select x,y from data_points)
    loop
      dist:= sqrt(((rec.X-aRow.X)**2)+((rec.Y-aRow.Y)**2)); 

      insert into temp values(dist);
    end loop;

    SELECT DISTANCE
      into result
      FROM (select distance, ROWNUM as RNUM
              from temp
              order by distance)
      where rnum = k;

    insert into nn_results values(aRow.ID, k, result);
  end loop;
end NN;
```

Using cursor FOR loops and row variables simplifies the code a great deal.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks. But this procedure does not seem to terminate as well.

Comment: I suspect that there are some logic issues in there which I can't diagnose because I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish, nor can I see the data you're using. One thing I noticed is that neither of the queries driving your loops have a WHERE clause so they're reading every row in those tables which might be part of the issue. You might want to create an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) so that people can mess with your data - and it might help you work out what's going on. Best of luck.

Comment: Yup we intend to read every part of the table. I am trying to get the Kth nearest neighbor of a spacial point. So I am calculating the distance of each point (in query_points) from the others (data_points) and storing these results temporarily in a table (temp). I then take the kth value in the temp table which is ordered by distance to be the kth nearest neighbor.

Comment: Ah - I think I see the problem now. The issue here is that ROWNUM isn't assigned until results are actually being returned from a query; thus if you say something like "SELECT * FROM TEMP WHERE ROWNUM = 92" you'll never get a result because to get to ROWNUM=92 you first have to select rows with ROWNUM=1 through 91. I've modified the `SELECT DISTANCE...` query in the code above to work around this issue. Share and enjoy.